# How many tupels $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \{0, \dots, c\}^n$ are there such that $\sum_i a_i = k$?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm currently stuck on the following problem:
Given $c,n,k\in \mathbb{N}_0$, what is the amount of tupels $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \{0, \dots, c\}^n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = k$? More precisely, what is
$$
z(n,c,k) := \left|\left\{(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \{0, \dots, c\}^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = k\right\}\right|
$$

Now, the case $c\leq 1$ is easy:
$$
z(n,0,k) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if $n=0$ or k=0}\\ 0 & \text{ else}\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
z(n,1,k) = \binom{n}{k}
$$
Also, if $c\geq k$ there is a rather easy solution:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&z(n,c,k)   &\\
& = & \left|\left\{(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \{0, \dots, c\}^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = k\right\}\right|\\
& = & \left|\left\{(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{N}_0^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = k\right\}\right|\\
& = & \binom{n+k-1}{k}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
since for every $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = k$ we must also have $a_i \leq k \leq c$ for all $i$.

But I'm having difficulties finding a **nice formula for the remainig case** $1<c<k$. Here are some ideas:

- By the above, we know that $$\binom{n}{k} \leq z(n,c,k) \leq \binom{n+k-1}{k}$$
- We also know that $$ z(n,c,k) = \sum_{a=0}^c z(n-1,c,k-a) $$ by partitioning the set by possible values of $a_1$.